# Mongoose.js: Find users, then check value of the user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to check if the user is an Admin, but I can not retrieve that value. When I log console.log(user) I get all these values:

```
email: 'testone@hotmail.com',
password:'$2b$10$mMyZkF3y8wxFTXUNgd/giuDvbaXfTFxlYECQmHgvAHDd4NB5CNpsq',
role: 'admin'
```

Now how do I check if the user role is === to 'admin'? 
I have tried to do `user.role`, `req.userData.role === 'admin'` but I can not seem to find it because its telling me undefined.

```
router.delete("/:id",
  authCheck,
  (req, res, next) => {
    User.find()
      .then(user => {
        console.log('*this log gives me undefined*', user.role);
        if (!req.userData.role === 'admin') {
          Post.deleteOne({
            _id: req.params.id,
            poster: req.userData.userId,
          }).then(result => {
            if (result.n > 0) {
              res.status(200).json({
                message: "Deletion successful!"
              });
            } else {
              res.status(401).json({
                message: "Not authorised!"
              });
            }
          })
        }
      })
  });
```

I know most of you will find this super simple but I'm only new to the backend so I'm choosing to post this as my last hope in fixing it, many thanks!

Comment: Yeah as mentioned @Sashi, when I `console.log(user);` I get all the records I want but then how do I grab something from it? I want to check if the user's role is admin.

Comment: @DavidJawHpan its undefined there too, that's why I'm asking how do I do the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `User.find()` is giving you an array of documents, and not an object of the document.

Try `user[0].role`

`!req.userData.role === 'admin'` is also an issue.
It should be `req.userData.role !== 'admin'` or `!(req.userData.role === 'admin')`

Also, it looks like your app is already loading the user from the database and attaching it to `req`. `passport.js` or something else must be doing that. If that's the case, you don't really need to do a `User.find()` again, as its already being done by your auth mechanism. This is just about the requester, if you are loading some other user for something else, ignore this rant.

Also, if you just want a single record that matches your query, try using `findOne` instead of `find`

Comment: Perfect, that's working fine, but I need to compare the current user's role do you know how I could work around that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm getting your whole scenario. Do you want to check the role of the user who has made the delete request?

Comment: Yes, and if the role is = to admin then it will be allowed. Currently, I had working that only the person that made the post can delete the post as seen on the `Post.deleteOne` section of the code, but now I've wrapped that around an if statement as can be seen in this post. Now I just need to compare the Id of the user who made the request to the id of an admin.

Comment: `!req.userData.role === 'admin'` should be `req.userData.role !== 'admin'`

Comment: See, if you are getting the requester's user object in `req.userData` or `req.user`. Most probably you are getting it. Then you can directly use that instead of loading the user. `User.find()` will give you list of all users.

Comment: `req.userData` gives me the email of the user requesting it, the userId and the role. The `req.user` gives me undefined.

Comment: `req.userData.role` Gives me the role of the person requesting it which is perfect! I am super close now... now all I have to do is compare?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174491/discussion-between-andrew-and-dushyant-bangal).